# How to change the color of single characters in a cell in excel with python win32com?

Tags: python, excel, fonts, win32com

I have a question regarding the win32com bindings for excel. I set up early bindings and followed some examples from the "Python Programming on Win32" book from O'Reilly.

The following code works fine:

```
book2.xlApp.Worksheets('Sheet1').Cells(1,1).Font.ColorIndex = 1
book2.xlApp.Worksheets('Sheet1').Cells(1,1).Font.ColorIndex = 2
```

It changes the font color of the whole cell according to the number.
However this does not work:

```
book2.xlApp.Worksheets('Sheet1').Cells(1,1).Characters(start,length).Font.ColorIndex = 1
```

I get the following callback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Characters instance has no __call__ method
```

However in Excels VBA the code works. Can anybody point me to the solution? 
I really need to change parts of a string in an excel cell.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

use GetCharacters:

```
Cells(1,1).GetCharacters(start,length).Font.ColorIndex = 1
```